# Require a mongodb db model deign. Whether to choose Refs or Embeded doc

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm designing a backend for a Talent hunt application. Initially I designed the DB using refs. Like I followed the primary key forign key using refs to join my collections. But as the collection requirement increases it's being hard to join all the collections. Then I come across the one to many collections. So I'm thinking to get a suggestion from experts. Let me tell the requirements.

I have the following collections initially.

**User.js**

```
{
    _id: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a4a14",
    name: "Lijo",
    email: "lijo@gmail.com"
}
```

then I have a category table for serving the categories

**Category.js**

```
{
    _id: 5ecfdc903165f709b49a5a18,
    title: "Acting",
    code: "ACT"
}
```

If one user adds his talents to profile. I used one another collection for storing. Rmember the user can save multilple talents. So i created,

**UserTalents.js**

```
{
    _id: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a6c87",
    categoryId: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a5a18",
    userId: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a4a14",
    level: "beginner"
}
```

For each catgeory need to upload atleast one media along with description Soagain I created a new collection for that.

**Media.js**

```
{
    _id: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a8a14",
    talentId: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a6c87",
    userId: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a4a14"
    media: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a4a14_1.jpg"
}
```

And I need to have these users connected. For that craeted.

**Friends.js**

```
{
    _id: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a8a18",
    sender: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a4a14",
    receiver: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a4a15"
    status: "accepted"
}
```

Is this good to continue??? Expecting a huge amount of users. Or can I follow like:

**User.js**

```
{
   _id: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a4a14",
   name: "Lijo",
   email: "lijo@gmail.com",
   talents: [ 
                {
                    _id: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a5a18", // _id from Category
                    title: "Acting", 
                    code: "ACT", 
                    level: "beginner", 
                    media: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a4a14_1.jpg"
                }
    ],
    friends: [
                 {
                      _id: "5ecfdc903165f709b49a4a15",
                      name: "Test",
                      status: "approved"
                 }
   ]
}
```

I I follow this, then how do I update the name fileds in talents and friends array either one of its original name is changed?

Which is better approach?

Comment: The truth is both refs and embedded document are great, which one to use heavily depends on the query requirements of your application. With NoSQL databases like MongoDB, *I* would generally go for embedding documents before I consider using refs. Embedding resonates fundamentally with the document structure of MongoDB and it provides read efficiency that most times outweighs the data denormalization it introduces to your data schema.

Comment: For write/updates to embedded documents, MongoDB provides very good query interfaces to deal with that, you can check out [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#read-operations-arrays), and [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#read-operations-embedded-documents) to start with.

Comment: I would use refs when the document association is really complex or when I’m not getting any clear read performance advantage with embedding i.e when I’m mostly writing to the data set and rarely reading from it. More details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/index.html)